# how not invoke specific method on spring batch

Tags: mockito, spring-batch

Is there a way with mockito to test my batch and tell to not invoke specific method that the process call **MyService.class**, inside that service i got some business logic in a specific method that i don't want him to invoke is that possible? I was sure that doing the **doReturn** will ignore my method (the method is public) but still get call.

```
   @Autowired
        private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;


        @Autowired
        private MyRepo myRepoRepository; 



        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void testJob() throws Exception {

        doReturn(true).when(spy(MyService.class)).validationETPer(any(Object.class), anyChar());
        doReturn(true).when(spy(MyService.class)).validationMP(any(Object.class),anyChar());
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(); 


        assertEquals(execution.getStepExecutions().size(), 1); 
    for (StepExecution stepExecution : execution.getStepExecutions()) {

            assertEquals(3, stepExecution.getReadCount()); 
            assertEquals(3, stepExecution.getWriteCount()); 
        }

        assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode(), execution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());

        assertEquals(2, myRepoRepository.count()); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does not what you believe it does:

```
doReturn(true).when(spy(MyService.class)).validationETPer(any(Object.class), anyChar());
```

`spy(MyService.class)` creates a new instance of `MyService` and spies on it. Of course, since you never use that instance, it's completely useless. There is an instance that is spied on, but you didn't store it anywhere, you didn't put it anywhere and so nobody will ever use it.

That line does **not** spy on every `MyService` in existence, as you seem to believe, it creates one concrete instance of `MyService` and spies on that. Obviously, that's not what you want here - you want to spy on the instance that is actually used in your code.

What you probably wanted to do, is more something like this...

```
MyService mySpy = spy(MyService.class);
doReturn(true).when(mySpy).validationETPer(any(Object.class), anyChar());
jobLauncherTestUtils.setMyService( mySpy ); // or something like that
// and NOW you can test
```

It's hard to go deeper in the details without knowing how the `MyService` is used in your actual code. Personally, I would suggest starting with unit tests without spring and using spring test only for higher level tests.

Comment: you were right stupid on me i spy on a new instance that isn't my bean and technically wonder why it didnt work but in the end i just instance a bean of my service inside configuration class and add profile test for it and work like a charm.

Comment: Ok, that's the good spring way to do it, using a profile, true ;-)